# How do I open files and URLs at runtime in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pascal

I want to add two buttons to a program I'm making in RAD Studio XE7:

- One that opens a webpage URL in the default browser;
- One that opens a PDF File in the default PDF reader.

How can I do that?

*P.S.: I tried using ShellExecute for the URL, but it returns the following error message: [dcc32 Error] Main.pas(44): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ShellExecute'.*

Comment: `ShellExecute/Ex()` is the correct solution for both cases (at least on Windows).  If you are having a problem with it, please show your actual code, and any error messages you are getting.

Comment: As Remy stated, showing your code and error message helps us help you. "..won't declare the identifier or something like that." Maybe it is "Undeclared identifier"? If so, did you add `WinAPI.ShellAPI` to your `uses` clause?

Comment: Your real problem is that you don't take error messages seriously. If you read the error message carefully you might understand it. Even if you don't understand this one, if you took the messages seriously you'd reproduce it verbatim. Declaring that "it won't declare the identifier or something like that" just indicates that you don't think errors contain information. Programming is all about detail. Be precise.

Answer (score 2):

```
uses ShellAPI;

// this opens a URL in the default browser

url := 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
ShellExecute(HInstance, 'open', PChar(url), nil, nil, SW_NORMAL);

// this opens any file with the default program assigned to that extension  

pdf := 'c:\data\stackoverflow.pdf';
ShellExecute(HInstance, 'open', PChar(pdf), nil, nil, SW_NORMAL);
```

Comment: (Instead of adding OS dependent shellexecute all over your code, in general it is best to make some helper functions per documenttype like opendocument, openurl etc)

Comment: OK, I guess that was the problem. But SW_NORMAL still causes error. ([dcc32 Error] Main.pas(44): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'SW_NORMAL')

Comment: @Rafael: You are aware that you can ask  the IDE to search for definitions in the VCL source? *Search->Find in Files* from the main menu, set the *Text to find*, check *Search in directories*, set the *File mask* to your Delphi version's source directory + `*.pas`, and check the *Include subdirectories* box. It will find the declarations of things for you, so we don't need to do so for you over and over again.

Comment: @Rafael I suggest that you learn the basics before attempting to proceed. At present it is clear that you don't understand Delphi's unit system. Please learn that so that you don't have to ask identical questions over and again for every identifier that you ever use.

Comment: SW_NORMAL is defined in the Windows unit, so add Windows to the uses clause. Otherwise, you can replace it by the number 1.